# 'clasp login' doesn't wait for response

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, command-line-interface, clasp

I am trying to login with clasp to clone and edit a project in Google Apps Script but I am having a failure.

Previously, on another computer I could login without problem, I sent the `clasp login` command and it waited for a response from the browser, but now what happens is that I send the `clasp login` command, it generates the url and opens the browser tab but apparently it doesn't wait for a response. What it finally does is that when confirming the login it redirects to localhost:port but there it does not connect and indicates that the connection has been refused.

I have tried to do it with `clasp login --no-localhost` but this method is deprecated and blocked by Clasp CLI.

I have checked in the firewall and Node.js Runtime is enabled for private and public networks. So I don't know what can be the problem.

I remain attentive to possible solutions, thanks.